# RGB Conversion in Lua/TI-Nspire (TI-image)

Tags: lua, rgb, ti-nspire

I know this may be kinda of a dead and old unanswered topic, but
im trying to convert a RGB color code to the string format in a TI-image file, which doesnt make sense to me here:

https://wiki.inspired-lua.org/TI.Image

I understand all it mentions, until I reach the rgb conversion part. The article says that each rgb color has to have 5 bits, but it doesnt tell how to convert it, and i cant make sense of how to convert it following the given example. For instance:

R=255   →   R = 31

G=012   →   G = 1

B=123   →   B = 15

What would I have to do to convert R255, G012 and B123 to the above output?

I understand the remaining instructions on the article, except this.

Anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: Convert every color component to 5-bit value (from 0..255 to 0..31) using formula `round(x*31/255)` and compose 16-bit pixel `ARRRRRGGGGGBBBBB`

Comment: Thanks You! I never saw that before, i tried to find a pattern in what made the numbers what they were in the output.